# $\lim_{N\to \infty}a\sqrt{2N^{2}+N+1}-bN=2,\text{then }a^{2}+b^{2}=??$

Tags: limits

I have made two approaches, first that I differentiate the equation to respect to $N$ as I am assuming it will converge and finally I get $a\sqrt{2}-b=0$.
Second approach is to neglect lower degrees for $N$ which means $$\lim_{N\to \infty}a\sqrt{2N^{2}+N+1}-bN=\lim_{N\to \infty}a\sqrt{2N^{2}}-bN=2$$
$$\lim_{N\to \infty}a\sqrt{2}N-bN=2$$
$$\lim_{N\to \infty}a\sqrt{2}-b=\frac{2}{N}$$
$$a\sqrt{2}-b=0$$
Which reach the same point.

What should I do next?

I now for sure that $a^{2}+b^{2}=96$, as $a=4\sqrt{2}$ and $b=8$.
How could we prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$\lim_{N\to \infty}a\sqrt{2N^{2}+N+1}-bN=\lim_{N\to \infty}a\sqrt{2N^{2}}-bN=2$$

This is incorrect.

$$\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{N\to \infty}a\sqrt{2N^{2}+N+1}-bN\\
\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{a\sqrt{2N^{2}+N+1}-bN}{a\sqrt{2N^{2}+N+1}+bN}\cdot (a\sqrt{2N^{2}+N+1}+bN)\\
\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{a^2(2N^{2}+N+1)-b^2N^2}{a\sqrt{2N^{2}+N+1}+bN}~~~~~\Rightarrow 2a^2=b^2\tag{1}\\
\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{a^2(N+1)}{a\sqrt{2N^{2}+N+1}+bN}\\
\\
&=\frac{a^2}{a\sqrt2 +b}=2\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Solve (1) and (2) and you get $a=4\sqrt{2}$ and $b=8$.